# How to distribute python script for parallel but sequential processing of large scale data?

Tags: python, multithreading, architecture, bigdata

Here is the scenario that we have to solve :

- Pull all PDF files from server.
- convert PDF to PNGs
- do some mining on PNGs and generate TXT
- parse TXT to generate CSV
- merge CSV

I have written a  python 
 function for each of the above tasks, there are total 5 functions, and the output of first function serves as the input for the second function, so we can't run all the above functions in parallel. One task needs to finish before the other can run.

There are multiple folders in which PDFs are saved, and this has to be entered manually, so currently we are manually running multiple instance of code, and specifying which folder to execute, new folders are keep on uploading with time.

Processing one folder takes about an hour, could someone suggest an architecture and tool to speed-up the entire process and to minimise the manual effort. You can suggest tools / libraries that we could consider using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like [apache-airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)

You define your process as a Direct Acyclic Graph.

Apache airflow will manage tasks dependencies and parallelization for you.

Be aware that no data will be sent from one task to the other. If you need tasks-communications, you'll need to define yourself how to do it (using database, files, ...)

Comment: for instance suppose there are `N` sub-folders inside a folder, these sub-folders contain PDF files, can we use airflow, provide a folder and it will then automate task and parallelisation for each of these sub-folders?

Comment: You will code a script to define the DAG executed by airflow. Inside this script, you will for example create 5 operators (pulling, converting, mining, parsing, merging). Then you will instantiate n times each operator and create Tasks, then add these tasks to the DAG. Airflow will not automate any task if you provide a folder, but you can. (you can create a script which instantiate as many Operators as you have subfolders inside your main folder). See the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#task-instances